# SEO: Integrating keywords with domain names

Tags: seo, domains, keywords

I have some questions regarding SEO and the best use of keywords in conjunction with corresponding domain names, and I thought it'd be best to pose the questions in the form of an example: Let's say I have a company called "Nick's Winery" with the domain "nicks-winery.com." I have a new product I'm launching that I've named "Rocket Red," the primary landing page for which is "nicks-winery.com/rocket-red." I want to optimize my search results for the keyword "rocket red,"-- thus, if one searches the term "rocket red," the Nick's Winery site would ideally show at the very top of the results page-- and in addition to providing a good deal of information on the actual product page, it's prominently referenced at the top of my homepage at nicks-winery.com. I've gone ahead and purchased the domain names "rocketred.com," "rocket-red.com," "rocketredwine.com," etc. and I have pointed them all to the primary Rocket Red page at "nicks-winery.com/rocket-red"-- thus, no duplicate content, just the one primary product page.

My question is as follows-- what further steps can I take to optimize for this keyword with respect to the domain names? Should I explicitly add all the domains I've purchased-- with both www and non-www variants-- into Google webmaster tools, and submit them to be indexed, even though they all point to the primary landing page within the "nicks-winery" domain? Is this even necessary? Should I even be pointing all the brand-name domains to that page in the first place, or would it be optimal to take a different approach? Should these keyword-specific domains in fact be pointed to just the "nicks-winery.com" instead of the specific product page?

Thanks for any insight here.

Comment: why you have purchased  "rocketred.com," "rocket-red.com," "rocketredwine.com," etc? To match your keyword with domain?

Comment: yes, the idea in this (hypothetical) example, is that the supplemental domains were purchased to assist SEO for the given keyword

Comment: I see. But that will not help you..:)

Answer (score 4):

Oh Lord you are wasting your time and money!

Keyword domain names do not count for much and will give you nothing more than a big bill at the end of the year.

Keyword matches do happen only in the very narrowest of circumstances for sites that have content and rank on their own. Purchasing multiple domains for the purpose of gaining an advantage does not work. Having multiple domain names for rank does not work. It is an old black-hat trick that was very very short lived when Google discovered the foolishness of it's theory (exact match keyword domains) and pulled it quickly. Unfortunately, we see this come up often even 2 years after Google pulling the plug.

You are always far better off creating one well optimized site and ranking for the things you should rank for.

There are no tricks, buttons, levers, magic incarnations, mystical potions, enchantments, and no even Bloody Mary cannot help you get better SEO.

There are too many people willing to spend money on useless domain names and too many people willing to take your money. Worse yet, there are the middle men that make you feel like you are doing the right thing for their own piece of the pie. Forget the non-sense and go straight for the one domain name and do damned good work and get your prize the old fashioned way- work for it. Stop fiddling about with silliness and get busy.

Comment: did you understand why NICK has purchased these domains?  "rocketred.com," "rocket-red.com," "rocketredwine.com," etc. For ranking to match keywork with domain? I am confuse for that sentence.

Comment: well, first off, the client purchased all the domains, thinking it would help in our specific instance. While I realize it might be overkill, I am surprised that ownership of the domains and pointing them to the primary site would not make much of a difference. This is not about magical tricks, but ways to get a bit of extra help for a specific keyword. If owning corresponding domain names really doesn't have much of an effect, then so be it.

Comment: @HelpingHands He has three problems: one, keyword domains do virtually nothing without content of their own; two, it appears that he wanted to redirect these domains to a sub-directory which cannot be done; and three     there it always the duplicate content issue if it applies.

Comment: @nickpish I certainly did not mean to sound critical if I did. Keyword matches do happen only in the very narrowest of circumstances for sites that have content and rank on their own. Purchasing multiple domains for the purpose of gaining an advantage does not work. Having multiple domain names for rank does not work. It is an old black-hat trick that was very very short lived when Google discovered the foolishness of it's theory (exact match keyword domains) and pulled it quickly. Unfortunately, we see this come up often even 2 years after Google pulling the plug. Sorry about your client.

Comment: @closetnoc no worries, I appreciate the response; while I didn't buy-- or even suggest buying-- all the domains, I certainly didn't realize that buying up keyword-oriented domains is considered a black-hat trick. I've focused on designing the best site I can with respect to content and semantics, and did think the extra domains could potentially help knock up the results a bit, but if not that's definitely good to know.

Comment: @nickpish For what it is worth, I realize that my last comment really should have been in the answer all along. I edited the answer for future users. You can always point your client to this page if it helps support any arguments you make. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: thanks-- I know he'll be disappointed, but the knowledge will definitely save him money in the future.

Comment: @nickpish SEO and designers see this all the time these days. People read all this SEO junk and believe it wholesale. It is a shame really. It leaves the rest of us to clean up the mess. I appreciate your concern and asking the question here. I tend to be rather frank on these issues. These answers I do not want to soft peddle. I hate all the old and often very wrong SEO advice out there from all the SEO peddlers trying to carve out a niche for themselves. I do what I can to set the record straight. If you can stand a bit of frankness, this is an excellent place for SEO questions. Honest!

Comment: @nickpish You are right. Also, he could have damaged his SEO score too. It is always wiser to have one domain k1ck @$$ than to spread efforts out amongst many.

Comment: @nickpish Confucius says- keep it simple. But what the h311 does he know?

Comment: @closetnoc I certainly appreciate the frankness, and also find it deeply upsetting that not only tons of hacks out there are offering trash advice, they're actually often getting paid for it. While I realize content and good design should always be the primary points of focus, I'm also curious to learn what other practices might exist to assist SEO from a technical standpoint, if that makes sense.

Comment: @closetnoc - Ohh. I see...

Comment: @nickpish The entire SEO industry short of a few, are people trying to carve out a niche for themselves in the SEO world. This would be fine if the industry was fact based. You have to remember that these folks are blackbox testing Google. There are some clues- especially if you know the industry from the inside and the technologies used. However, most are marketing people or hackers of some sort and the speculation can be all over the place. Worse yet, people parrot what they read and almost nothing is ever deleted or updated. Google is responsible for intentionally muddy waters.