# Translated text on multiple national level domains

Tags: seo, domains, keywords, multiple-domains, multilingual

I am a bit confused about multilingual websites and SEO and would be grateful if somebody could explain me how they are ranked at the moment.

For example, my company's website domain is "problemsolver.com". I sell a range of products and one of them, for example, simplifies cow milking a lot.
In order to increase sales for this particular product I started working on SEO and one of the SEO specialists advised me to create a landing page specifically for that product. This guy will provide me a few SEO-optimized articles about my product, cows, milking, etc. Also
we identified that one of the best search phrases to optimize for would be "efficient cow milker".
Since the product is pretty niche I don't expect to receive many incoming links (if any at all). So my SEO strategy is based purely on the available content.

Since I'm going to create a separate landing page, I need a new domain name. My personal favorite is "efficient-cow-milker.com" because it is very explicit and easy to remember.
But will it bring me additional ranking points? [This answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77695/75405) says no, [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/87655/75405) (refers to https://moz.com/search-ranking-factors) states the opposite.

***UPDATE**: [this newer article states](https://backlinko.com/google-ranking-factors#domain) that full keywords match has very little effect at best BUT keyword in the subdomain helps ranking*

Now the problem is that my product is sold in multiple non-English speaking regions where people don't google "red cow milker" but rather something like "effizienter Kuhmelker". Therefore all the content must be translated and SEO-optimized for each region separately.

Taking into account these facts, what do you think about:

1. Multiple regional domain names like "efficient-cow-milker.com", "effizienter-kuhmelker.de" and "mungitrice-efficiente.it"? I read here that regional domains are better for targeting and people open regional websites more often. Also in my case domain names are easy to remember and fully match relevant search phrases. Will it help ranking?
2. Won't google ban my regional domains? As I said, content will be translated and optimized, so technically each website is a copy of an English version. I could introduce some uniqueness for each text translation but not for graphics. Should I bother or Google won't notice duplication?
3. if all of the landing pages with similar content are hosted on the same IP address, won't it be recognized as something bad and penalized? Or is it the opposite: Google sees multiple websites with similar content but in different languages on the same IP and doesn't penalize them?
4. should I link all of the landing pages between each other or better not to?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt do it. From my experience, exact match of keyword in domain name doesnt worth it. It does work, yes, but from my perspective it is more reasonable in your case to create multi language site.